# Is OpenSSL enc using AES-256-CBC to encrypt large files safe?

Tags: encryption, aes, openssl

I first generate a keyfile with `openssl rand -hex 64 -out keyfile`.

I then encrypt the file with `openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in large_file.zip -out large_encrypted.bin -pass file:./keyfile`.

I am encrypting files sized anywhere from a few bytes to 1TB. I will be using this in a simple bash script.

1. Is this secure in 2021? Should I use a different cipher?
2. Can any metadata leak from the encrypted file?
3. Should/can the keyfile be larger than 64 bytes?
4. Should I create new keyfiles for each file I encrypt?
5. Is there a minimum/maximum file size this can encrypt? Do different file sizes affect security?
6. Is this considered "rolling my own crypto" (which I know is widely discouraged)?

Comment: Why do you choose CBC instead of AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305. Encrypted data only contains IV nothin more since AES is secure. Well, why don't you use a VeraCrypy volume to store these files? Also see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87033/18298)

Comment: OpenSSL command line only supports less-secure modes like CBC. A VeraCrypt volume would use XTS, which also isn't an AEAD. It's also a lot harder to ensure no nonce reuse with file encryption and a short nonce like GCM uses. XChaCha20-Poly1305 can use a random nonce safely due to its eXtended nonce length.

Comment: I need to encrypt files on demand and individually. VeraCrypt does not seem to be able to do that. OpenSSL is not a requirement, it is just the best tool I've found that fits (or at least, seems to fit) my requirements. @SAIPeregrinus

Comment: https://age-encryption.org is what I'd recommend. It's built for file encryption, can generate a secure passphrase (eliminating the weak password problem), and uses an actual AEAD unlike OpenSSL, Veracrypt, and GPG. Example use: `age -p -o output.age input.txt` would encrypt `input.txt` into a file `output.txt` and print the passphrase it used. You could also pass in your own passphrase, but I recommend against this. If you want to encrypt lots of files, use its SSH key options.